# Getting null with json_decode()

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm attempting to update records through decoded JSON by ID in this CakePHP function:

```
public function update() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $decoded = json_decode($this->request->data,true);
        if($data = $this->Foobar->save($decoded)) {
            $data = json_encode(array(
                "message" => "Foobar successfully updated.",
                "update" => $this->request->data
            ));
        } else {
            $data = json_encode(array(
                "message" => "Foobar could not be updated.",
                "update" => $decoded,
                "updateJson" => $this->request->data
            ));
        }
    } else {
        $data = json_encode(array(
            "message" => "Method should be post."
        ));
    }
    $this->set('data', $data);
```

But the decode keeps returning `null`:

```
{"message":"Foobar could not be updated.","update":null,"updateJson":{"ID":"1","status":2}}
```

However, if I go to http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php and enter:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<pre>
<?php
   print_r(json_decode('{"ID":"1","status":2}', true));
?>
</pre>
</body></html>
```

It works just fine...

Looking at related questions...

- I've seen suggestions to try `json_last_error()`, this returns `0` for me.
- I've seen someone mention `magic_quotes` might be on, mine are off.
- I've seen suggestions to use `json_decode(utf8_encode($this->request->data),true);`, this still returns `null` for me

Any ideas?

Comment: `$this->request->data` do var_dump on it and check if its valid json

Comment: What is the URL you are calling it with? .json extension included?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, I guess I assumed that when I included `$this->request->data` in the `data` and it shows valid json `{"ID":"1","status":2}` it would mean it's valid json... however there must be some stuff going on behind the scenes as the `var_dump` is showing an array ...`array(2) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["status"]=>
  int(2)
}`

Comment: Looking at the above, it would seem to make sense that I could do... `$this->Foobar->save($this->request->data)`, but when I do this I am getting `Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`. It appears it is trying to do an insert rather than an update, however http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html states `If you want to update a value, rather than create a new one, make sure you are passing the primary key field into the data array`, and I am doing that.

Comment: Meh.. I didn't have `$primaryKey` set in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should JSON Decode the data.

Try to directly save:

```
$data = $this->Foobar->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Hi, please see comments above. It seems like this should work as I guess the JSON is automatically being decoded... but it seems CakePHP is trying to insert rather than update even though the primary key was included.

Comment: Well, anyway I suppose this is actually the answer to why it's returning `null`.